# How to setup eclipse to work with subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn

I've been using eclipse for a couple years and I had it setup with subversion (subclipse). I don't really use subversion directly in eclipse but it is useful when refactoring (e.g., changing the name of a file or moving a file to another package) because it would do the adds and moves for me and becomes almost impossible to refactor without this feature.

But I upgraded to indigo and my subversion libraries were gone. So I installed subclipse again (1.6, using SVNKit 1.3.5) and it seems to recognize all my repository settings. However, when I do any refactoring it doesn't do any of the behind the scenes changes it used to.

For example, if I rename a file it seems to create the file and update all of the code references, but when I do a 'svn status' on the command line it doesn't have the 'D' (deleting existing file) and 'A+' (adding with history) that I'd expect, but instead has a '!' (original file missing) and '?' (don't recognize new file).

Any suggestions? This was working fine before the upgrade to indigo.

I have also tried using subversive but had the same problems.  I also tried subclipse 1.8 but it seems to only use the HL version of subversion and I'm on a mac and would prefer the pure java (SVNKit) option.  My local subversion client is version 1.6 (default on Mac OSX.7).